# Partitioned parquet files with two different schemas, Athena can get the data based on partition?. maintain seperate schema per partition internally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue, amazon-athena

### Please help on it:

I have a parquet file which has more than one partition of data. and each partition has different schema associated with it.
I want to create a glue table on top of it and get data based on the partition selected.

**Ex :Here are the sample datafiles with different schema**

### File1:

S3://mybucket/emp_info/year=2018/month=01/day=01/

**Schema associated with it:**

column_name        │ column_type

id                │ INTEGER     │
first_name        │ VARCHAR     │
salary            │ **DOUBLE**

### File2:

S3://mybucket/emp_info/year=2019/month=01/day=01/

**Schema associated with it:**
DOB column is the new column added and salary column type changed from double to integer

column_name        │ column_type

id                │ INTEGER     │
first_name        │ VARCHAR     │
salary            │ **INTEGER** │
**DOB**           | DATE        |

want to create a crawler on the dataset **S3://mybucket/emp_info/** and query based on the partition but schema should be automatically identified based on the partition we querying?

I dont want to create a seperate table for each partition.

**Query and expected result on Athena:**

select * from emp_info where year=2018 and month=01 and day=01;
***Expected output with 3 columns (id, first_name, salary)  and data

select * from emp_info where year=2019 and month=01 and day=01;
***Expected output with 4 columns (id, first_name, salary, **DOB**)  and data

Any alternate and feasible solutions are welcome.